# Jdbc connection using java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have Rest-Api in the java.

That will take dbUrl, dbUserName, dbPassWord, dbDriver and sql query

and gives me the result set and after I will be converting into json format.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
connectionUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + server + ":" + dbName + "";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userName, password);
try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    output = resultSetHandler(stmt.executeQuery(query)); // this method convert ResultSet to Json
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new Error(e);
} finally {
    try {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new Error(ex);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that When 30 users use this api at one time means It will throw an error for few users....
and also I will not be using just oracle and I will be using postgres, mysql also

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error.

Comment: Creating a connection for each time your method is called will have problems since your DBMS server might have limit on how many connections can be made concurrently. For better solution use connection pools which will reuse the same connection.

Comment: This code won't compile.  You can't have two `finally` blocks in the same `try`.

Comment: When you say "That will take dbUrl, dbUserName, dbPassWord, dbDriver and sql query", do you mean that these data will be sent in an API request?

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider using DB connection pool such as [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) or [C3P0](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) (both available at Maven Repository). Opening a connection every time is very inefficient and you may run out of connections which may be the error you are getting.  Please post your error.
2. Use try-with-resources instead of doing the finally block.  It will automatically call close() on Autoclosable objects such as Connection, Statement, PreparedStatement, ResultSet, etc.

> ```
> try (
>     Connection myConnection = MyConnectionPool.getConnection();
>     Statement stmt = myConnection.createStatement();
>     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)
> ) {
>     // Do work with rs
> }
> ```